# Run All Test Projects At Once With dnx and Global.json

Tags: .net, testing, mono, dnx

Is there an option to have dnx run tests for all the test projects within the global.json file? Or is the best option to have some bash script that just goes through all directories of *.Tests and runs dnx test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no out-of-the-box feature that allows you to run a command on multiple projects. You have to do iterate through each project and invoke it.

We (the ASP.NET team) iterate through each project and invoke `test`, if available: https://github.com/aspnet/Universe/blob/5ed05d34acafb803164b46eeab8216a1f4752fe6/build/_k-standard-goals.shade#L209-L220